# How can I deserialize a json object into a json string?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following json:

```
{
  "name" : "tim",
  "items" : {
    "car" : "Mercedes",
    "house" : "2 Bedroom"
  }
}
```

The object to deserialize into is:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Items {get;set;}
}
```

I want to deserialize `items` into a string of the json object. So `Items` in this example should be

```
"{\"car\" : \"Mercedes\",\"house\" : \"2 Bedroom\"}"
```

I don't care about spacing such as tabs or new lines. How can I do this using `Newtonsoft.Json`? I've tried making a `JsonConverter<string>` as shown [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) but `reader.Value` comes up as `null`.

**Edit:** I would like to avoid deserializing `items` and then serializing it into a string again as I do not know what shape `items` will be and it may also be large.

Comment: I'm a little unclear with that exactly you want to do. If you have the json written properly in a file, string text = File.ReadAllText(pathToFile); var deserializedItem = JsonConvert<Person>(text);
If you just want to get the json string from an object:
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);

Comment: @HotTowelie please see my edit

Comment: So you want to deserialize a json property Items from a file, without deserializing the whole object, and get it as a json string? Unless I'm missing something, then you don't really want to deserialize it, you just want to find and read it with a text reader?

Answer (score 2):

After some help from the other answers here and looking at the docs some more, I discovered the [`JObject.Load`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Load.htm) method. My converter works now, and looks like this:

```cs
public class StringConverter : JsonConverter<String>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, String value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override Version ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Version existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JObject.Load(reader).ToString();
    }
}
```

And I can now use the attribute like this:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringConverter))]
    public string Items {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```cs
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
string itemsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person.Items);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to avoid deserializing `items` and then serializing it again, as `items` may be large and I do not know what shape it will be. Please see my edit.